Display a redirect domain on Bing search results?
Is there any way to show a redirect domain on Bing search? I have already added my redirect domain to Bing Webmaster Tools, but it doesn't seem to be showing up in the search results. Here's what I see on Bing Webmaster Tools
I added my redirect domain to Bing Webmaster Tools, hoping it would display in Bing search results. That's all I did so far.
